# Retrieve a Character's Virtual Key Code In VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, char

What I am looking for as a solution is a way to get the virtual key code value (used in many API functions) for a given character; this character can be given by the user and part of the program involves using GetASyncKeyState to check if the key corresponding to this character is pressed.

The closest solution I have found so far (see code below) is using VkKeyScanEx with the input locale identifier as that of the current thread (`GetKeyboardLayout(0)`), however, the [MSDN description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646332%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) states that only the low-order byte of the return value contains the key code; if this solution would work, how would I get this value?  If not, what should I use?

Current implementation: `Dim keyCode As Integer = VkKeyScanEx(userInputChar, GetKeyboardLayout(0))`

Comment: You will need to add the supporting code for this one line to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the low order byte of a `Short` value you can call this Method:

```
''' <summary>
''' Gets the low-order byte of an 'Int16' value.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="Value">Indicates the 'Int16' value that contains both the LoByte and the HiByte.</param>
''' <returns>The return value is the low-order byte.</returns>
Public Shared Function GetLoByte(ByVal value As Short) As Byte

    Return BitConverter.GetBytes(value).First

End Function
```

I've written for you this full example:

[image]

In the image you can see the character `#`, the keycode that returns the `VkKeyScanEx` func, the low order byte that contains the virtual key code, and the '6' indicates the state of the special keys, which in the case of that character are `Alt`+`Control` (2+4)

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Test() Handles MyBase.Shown

        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        Dim c As Char

        For Each k As Keys In (From s As Keys
                               In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(Keys))
                               Where s.ToString.Length = 1)

            ' LowerCase
            c = CChar(k.ToString.ToLower)
            sb.AppendFormat("Key    : {0}", c)
            sb.AppendLine()
            sb.AppendFormat("KeyCode: {0}", CStr(GetKeyCode(c)))
            sb.AppendLine()
            sb.AppendFormat("LoByte : {0}", CStr(GetLoByte(GetKeyCode(c))))
            sb.AppendLine()
            sb.AppendFormat("HiByte : {0}", CStr(GetHiByte(GetKeyCode(c))))
            MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString)
            sb.Clear()


            ' UpperCase
            c = CChar(k.ToString.ToUpper)
            sb.AppendFormat("Key    : {0}", c)
            sb.AppendLine()
            sb.AppendFormat("KeyCode: {0}", CStr(GetKeyCode(c)))
            sb.AppendLine()
            sb.AppendFormat("LoByte : {0}", CStr(GetLoByte(GetKeyCode(c))))
            sb.AppendLine()
            sb.AppendFormat("HiByte : {0}", CStr(GetHiByte(GetKeyCode(c))))
            MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString)
            sb.Clear()

        Next k

    End Sub

    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="VkKeyScanEx", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
    Friend Shared Function GetKeyCode(
                           ByVal c As Char,
                           Optional ByVal KeyboardLayout As UIntPtr = Nothing
    ) As Short
    End Function

''' <summary>
''' Gets the low-order byte of an 'Int16' value.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="Value">Indicates the 'Int16' value that contains both the LoByte and the HiByte.</param>
''' <returns>The return value is the low-order byte.</returns>
Public Shared Function GetLoByte(ByVal value As Short) As Byte

    Return BitConverter.GetBytes(value).First

End Function

''' <summary>
''' Gets the high-order byte of an 'Int16' value.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="Value">Indicates the 'Int16' value that contains both the LoByte and the HiByte.</param>
''' <returns>The return value is the high-order byte.</returns>
Public Shared Function GetHiByte(ByVal value As Short) As Byte

    Return BitConverter.GetBytes(value).Last

End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation of how to use key codes in a VB.NET program; I find that what you have included is much more than I need to use, but I will nonetheless mark it as my accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim virtualKeyCode As Integer = keyCode And &HFF
```

valter